# Splitting file path using Python

Tags: python

Suppose we have two file paths

```
C:\User\JohnDoe\Desktop\Happy\Happy\Expression\Smile.exe

C:\User\JohnDoe\Desktop\Happy\Expression\Smile.exe
```

We need to extract file path after the last mention of Happy.

Desired string should be

```
..\Expression\Smile.exe
```

for both cases.

How do we achieve this using python?

I thought of using split function

```
a = 'C:\\User\\JohnDoe\\Desktop\\Happy\\Happy\\Expression\\Smile.exe'

b = 'C:\\User\\JohnDoe\\Desktop\\Happy\\Expression\\Smile.exe'

print( a.split("Happy"))
print('..'+b.split("Happy")[1])
```

Output

```
['C:\\User\\JohnDoe\\Desktop\\', '\\', '\\Expression\\Smile.exe']
..\Expression\Smile.exe
```

I know that the first print statement is incorrect.
Is there any cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the last element after the split:

```
a = 'C:\\User\\JohnDoe\\Desktop\\Happy\\Happy\\Expression\\Smile.exe'

print(a.split("Happy")[-1])
```

output:

```
\Expression\Smile.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `.rsplit` method which accepts maximal number of splits as 2nd argumet:

```
path1 = r"C:\User\JohnDoe\Desktop\Happy\Happy\Expression\Smile.exe"
path2 = r"C:\User\JohnDoe\Desktop\Happy\Expression\Smile.exe"
print(path1.rsplit("Happy",1)[-1])
print(path2.rsplit("Happy",1)[-1])
```

output

```
\Expression\Smile.exe
\Expression\Smile.exe
```